# How do I play the last chord of Wieniawksi's Scherzo-Tarantelle, Op. 16?

Tags: chords, technique, violin, harmonics

At the end of Scherzo-Tarantelle (and also at the end of the first presto), there is a chord with three normal notes, and the fourth is an artificial harmonic. I know the harmonic works, because I tried it separately. Each time I play the chord, the fourth note, the harmonic, just won't work. It produces strange sounds (Edit: I checked the note, it is one octave lower than the desired sound), as if the chord's other notes' resonance disturbed the harmonic. And each time, I keep my hands still, and try the harmonic separately, it works. So is there a way to be able to play it with the chord or am I doing something wrong?
[image: Wieniawski's "Scherzo-Tarantelle", op. 16, end of the first Presto]

Comment: I make that *4* normal notes *and* a C harmonic. On 4 violin strings? What am I not getting?

Comment: Actually, I don't recall hearing that harmonic in *any* of the recordings I've heard of this piece (assuming you mean the Wieniawski one).

Comment: @Tim The notation means to hold down the solid note (the G) and lightly touch at the place where one would play the hollow note (i.e. at a fourth above where one is holding down). This produces a harmonic two octaves above the held note, since the division of a string corresponding to playing the higher note is to reduce the string's length to 3/4; so one is generating the harmonic at 1/4 the string length.

Comment: And each time I do it (just to clarify more), it makes a sound one octave lower, and the sound resonates strangely.

Answer (score 4):

One way to play it that might make it easier is to split this chord in two bows: the first 4 notes in a down-bow (G-D-Bb-G) and then do an up-bow to play the harmonic. Check for example minute 5:26 of this video (at speed x0.5 for best observation):

Answer (score 1):

As normal, you play the lower two strings open. You then play the Bb on the A string. On the E string though, you hold down the note G while lightly placing your 4th finger where C would be creating that false harmonic.